# The w3wp.exe process crashes and restarts hourly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am hosting an ASP.NET MVC site at arvixe.com. The IIS app server process, w3wp.exe keeps crashing and restarting once every hour, at approximately the same time (:35 to :45 pas the hour), even when there is not traffic (no pages are being served).

Arvixe technical support is either unable or unwilling to help me. They sent me a "dump" of a log file of 5607 lines which lists 243 exceptions. Summary:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| Count | Exception                                             |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 234   | Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler |
| 5     | System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException   |
| 3     | System.String                                         |
| 1     | System.Web.HttpCookie                                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The 5 crypto exceptions are:

```
Type:     System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Message:  Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
```

and they are all emitted by the login process (ASP._Page_Views_Account_Login_cshtml.Execute() [...\wwwroot\Views\Account\Login.cshtml @ 39]).

All other exceptions (HttpCookie, String, LangCompiler):

```
    Message:  NOT_FOUND
    Type:     NOT_FOUND
    Message:  NOT_FOUND
```

About as helpful as the arvixe.com support staff. The server's control panel shows 87.89 Gb of total and 51.12 Gb available memory. The process working set memory averages 220 Mb, ranging from 180 Mb to 250 Mb.

Could one of you gentlepeople help me?

Comment: Are you properly disposing all objects that should be disposed of?

Comment: Just a thought, are you sure it is crashing and apppool is not recycling at regular intervals?

Comment: No, it could be recycling. Support says they have no PowerShell scripts, only config limits...

Comment: All of my IDisposable objects are accessed from within using statements. So yes, I am disposing objects properly.

Comment: Users are not getting logged off prematurely since I've added a MachineKey to web.config but there is a serious performance hit once an hour.

Comment: According to arvixe.com support, the app pool is not recycling. Only w3wp.exe is terminating regularly every hour and restarting, even if there is no traffic to the site.

Comment: The arvixe server is running IIS version 8.0 while my local server, where the site runs flawlessly, is running IIS version 10.0. Could this be the cause???

Comment: I have deleted the website, recreated it and reloaded all of its assets. Still the same results, w3wp.exe terminates and restarts once every hour.